# How to make elements take up full width when body is wider than 100%?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

This works fine for most browsers because of bootstrap responsiveness. But I am checking on older browsers and found this.

[image]

It appears that the wide element is pushing out body. Okay, but then why isn't navbar taking up the full width?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ahacq8bc/4/).
"links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code":

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">The Navbar</a>
 </nav>
 <div></div>
body {
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:green;
  width: 3000px;
}
```

Comment: Did you include bootstrap.js?

Comment: No, I don't want to include bootstrap.js. But I just tried and it didn't work: https://jsfiddle.net/ahacq8bc/17/

Comment: remove the `div {width: 3000px;}`

Comment: But that's what simulates having wide content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is because the body max-width is limited to a 100% of viewport by default.

width:100% is the maximum width of the viewport or display device. In this case the width 3000px of that div exceeds well beyond the viewport limit. Hence 100% won't work. You can either explicitly define 3000px for the navbar.

But if you define width 3000px for the body, then Navbar also gets expanded to the same.
[check this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0cxbaLm5/6/)

```
body {
  background-color: red;
  width:3000px;
}
```

Comment: That's kind of what I figured. A little JavaScript snippet would probably get it but I bet would create more problems. I think I'm just going to ignore this one. It looks great on every browser I tried except safari on ios 6 and 5.1. ios 6 came out in 2012. So it's kind of a small issue anyhow and only on some old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Navigational bar inherits the width of the parent container. Add another class with `width: 3000px` ex- `fullWidth` as below:
`

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark fullWidth">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">The Navbar</a>
</nav>
<div></div>
body {
  background-color: red;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:green;
  width: 3000px;
}
.fullWidth {
  width: 3000px;
}
```

`

But a more cleaner way would be to set the parent container's(`body` in this case) width to 3000px, which will also avoid the duplication.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">The Navbar</a>
</nav>
<div></div>
body {
  background-color: red;
  width: 3000px;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background-color:green;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add this line in your css

```
.navbar .navbar-dark{
 width: 100%;
}
```

Check this I think this will work

Comment: That's what I thought at first too but no luck .